# undefined method `set' for nil:NilClass Redis Ruby

Tags: ruby, redis

i have a problem with my ruby script, when i try to insert datas into redis with the following command:

```
redis.set(key,value)
```

the console say me:

```
undefined method `set' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

i dont understand why doesnt work, i insert require "redis" in the script, i installed the correct gem, redis-server run correctly,
and this is my redis connection from ruby script:

```
redis = Redis.new(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6379, db: 0)
```

this is an example of my script, i cant share it cause of sensible datas:

```
require "redis"
begin
  redis = Redis.new(host:"127.0.0.1", port: 6379, db: 0)
rescue => error
  p error
end
redis.set("pizza", "bufala")
redis.close()
```

Comment: _"this is an example of my script"_ – do you get the same error when running that example? Does `p error` output anything?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to add an error handling around the Redis connection to make sure is done properly

```
begin
  redis = Redis.new(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6379, db: 0)
rescue => e
  puts "Failed to connect to Redis: #{e}"
end
```

Also make sure that the 'redis' variable connection is accesible from where you're trying to call 'redis.set(key,value)'.
Can you give the full structure of your script, that might be something else...

Comment: i just edit the question include an example of my script,

Comment: anyway the connection with redis works fine, the probelem seems like the set method adn the class redis

Comment: Move redis.set("pizza", "bufala") and redis.close bellow the redis connection variable, that should work. (watch out the syntaxError ("pizza", "bufala")

Comment: ok it works, fine thank you so much, but can you explain why, i tried with otherDB like mongo or mysql and i never had this problem

Comment: @YasuoPlayer having a undefined variable is clearly a Ruby issue, it doesn't have anything to do with the database you are using.

Comment: ok thank you so much